# 2D to 3D with parallel projection

Tags: c, rendering, projection

I'm trying to do parallel projection in C.

**My function:**

```
void parallel_projection(int x, int y, int z, float angle);
```

It is necessary to pass 3D coordinates to 2D using the parallel projection with the parameters of the function.

What is the formula to use to find x and y? (Using cos, sin and tangent)

Comment: Draw it on paper and deduce the formula.

Answer (score 0):

[Parallel Projection - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oblique_projection#Oblique_pictorial)

In your image, x and wx is the same axis, and angle is in yoz plane. So wx = x.

projected y:

when y = 0,
wy = z * cos(pi/2 - α) = z * sin(α)

when y > 0 and z < 0,
wy = sqrt(y^2 + z^2) * cos(α + arctan(z / y) + pi)

otherwise,
wy = sqrt(y^2 + z^2) * cos(α + arctan(z / y))

Note that angle is given in degree, while in C, trigonometric functions accept radian.

Comment: No but thanks for your reply !

Good english: http://img4.hostingpics.net/pics/548645Sanstitre.jpg

Comment: Okay, now the question is more clear. See my edited answer.